# Mockito: mocking a khttp object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

In a unit test, how do I mock the response received from a call to khttp's put() method?

```
val response : Response = khttp.put(myUrl, params = myParams, data = myData)
```

I will need to mock the khttp object somehow in order to return a mock Response object, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I would rather suggest to use mockk as a mocking library instead of mockito
then you could do something like this `mockkStatic("khttp.KHttp")  every { khttp.put(any(), any(), any()} returns YourMockResponse`, you can find more info here https://mockk.io/#extension-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the recommendation of @szymon_prz, I have used mockk (https://mockk.io/) instead of Mockito.